# Which Linux distribution has the capability to completely disable the automatic update?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, distributions

In **windows 7** we can disable automatic updates **completely**. But in **linux distributions** like **fedora** & **ubuntu** even after disabling automatic updates, they consume my bandwidth.
 I have limited bandwidth each month and I want to completely disable automatic update. Which linux distro has this capability?

Comment: None of them. Perhaps you could edit your hosts file to block the update URLs

Comment: @spuder: All of them, surely?

Comment: If there is no one, so which distribution is updated infrequently? @spuder

Comment: Can you offer me the distribution with this feature? @MichaelHomer

Comment: Or at least infrequently updated? @MichaelHomer

Answer (score 2):

I should think all Linux distributions can be configured in such a way that they never download package updates (including repository information) automatically. In some cases it might involve disabling a number of different pieces of software, but it should be doable...

Look at your system's cron jobs, systemd timers, and the setup of PackageKit, GNOME Software etc.

I know I have some Debian systems which generate no Internet trafic, but that's not something specific to Debian — it should be possible to set any Linux system up that way.